# Zero article before the word "settlement"

Tags: articles, zero-article

> After the middle of the fourth millennium the increase of permanently
> settled population in central Babylonia was minor and can be explained
> as the result of natural growth. In the south around the city of Uruk,
> however, there was an enormous escalation in the area occupied by
> **permanent settlement**.

(from *A History of the Ancient Near East by Marc Van De Mieroop*)

While I have no difficulties in understanding of this excerpt general meaning, I wonder why the bolded (by me) phrase is not prepended with an article here.

According to dictionaries (for example, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/settlement)), the word *settlement* may refer to either a place or the process of settling (of course, we do not consider other, irrelevant, meanings).

As far as I can see, the author relates about the specific inhabited place - that around the city of Uruk. And it is hard to say that *permanent settlement* conveys the meaning of the generalized idea of all settled places here, so the phrase needs the definite article, doesn't it?

Comment: The author is talking, not about the growth of the city itself, but the area around the city. I imagine that 'the area occupied by permanent settlement' may have included many small villages covering an increasingly large area.

Comment: I think the justification for not having an article before *[permanent] **settlement*** here turns on the fact that it's being used as an ***abstract noun*** - referencing *the **act** of settlement / the **state** of being settled*, rather than the more "concrete" noun usage referring to *an actual **location** which has been settled*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merriam-Webster gives a third definition of "settlement":

> **3a :** occupation by settlers

and this is the one being used here.

> there was an enormous escalation in the area occupied by permanent **occupation by settlers**.

So it's neither the place nor the process of occupying, but the ongoing *state* of settlers occupying the space.

In this context, "settlement" is a general concept, not a specific instance, so zero article is correct.

Comment: I agree with you but still feel a bit confusing because of the used verb *to occupy*.  Just IMHO, when particular land is *occupied by something*  it connotates **a** (specific) settlement, not the state of being settled. What if one'd say *the area **under** permanent settlement*, does it sound good?

Comment: @IlyaLoskutov You're right that when you parse the sentence, it doesn't make perfect sense. Yes, "under permanent settlement" is a better way to phrase it.